# Control AIF document service schema

Tags: schema, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, generated, aif

On Dynamics AX 2012 R3 CU8 when you use the wizard to create a document service, the system generates the schema for the different operations in the service. Is there a way to control what gets generated?

For example, if I create a query with HcmWorker as the parent and DirPerson as the child with just a few fields that I'm interested in, the system generates the schema with a few things I don't like, out of which I'll mention a couple below:

1. It adds fields like AxdEntity_DirPerson_DirParty.Name even though I explicitly didn't include this field in the query
2. The minOccurs on this field is  1, which doesn't work because it is a computed field. I prefer that this field is not included. If that is not possible, at least I would like to have minOccurs = 0

To make matters even more intriguing, the standard service (HcmWorkerImportService) for importing workers has the minOccurs = 0 for the Name field.

I'm trying to figure out how to control these values.

Comment: After a little bit of research, I found that fields such as Name and NameSequence are added to teh schema because they are tagged as mandatory in the tables. I still don't know how Microsoft changes these values in their standard services.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the `initMandatoryFieldsMap` method from the `AxdBase` class and overwrite it if needed in your `HcmWorkerImportService`.

> The initMandatoryFieldsMap method specifies which fields are mandatory
>   in the XML that the document class sends or receives. This method is
>   used to specify mandatory fields for the document without specifying
>   them at the table level.

See: [MSDN: Walkthrough: Creating a Service Using the AIF Document Service Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc589855(v=ax.50).aspx) (*"To override the initMandatoryFieldsMap method"*)

Example:

```
protected void initMandatoryFieldsMap() 
{ 
    super();   
    this.setParmMethodAsMandatory(classnum(AxdSalesOrder), 
                                  methodstr(AxdBase,parmDocPurpose)); 
}
```

See: [AxdBase.initMandatoryFieldsMap Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axdbase.initmandatoryfieldsmap.aspx)